# How do I track the performance of dynamic links created with the REST API (programmatically) in the Firebase console?

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using jQuery ajax request to make dynamic links but it doesn't show up in firebase dynamic links analytic console to keep track of its events.
as per firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links), it supposed to do so... any insight will be highly appreciated ...

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=" + api_key,
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    data:JSON.stringify({
      "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "dynamicLinkDomain": "yx55s.app.goo.gl",
        "link": cLink,
          "socialMetaTagInfo": {
            "socialTitle": sTitle,
            "socialDescription": sDesc,
            "socialImageLink": sImg
          }
        },
        "suffix": {
          "option": option
        }
      })
  }).done(function(links){
    console.log(links);
    $('.response').text(links.shortLink);
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, when I create via REST. Any progress since?

Comment: well as per firebase dev.  not appearing in the Dynamic Links dashboard is an intended behavior but can be tracked on Analytics dashboard. You may have to specify the Dynamic Link parameters particularly the Analytics parameters (utmSource, utmMedium, utmCampaign, etc). Also, see [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics.)"

I did that but still not working let me know if it works for you...cheers

Answer (score 6):

As de.sk mentioned, Dynamic Links created through the API don't appear in the Dynamic Links section of the console.

However, there is now a REST API to allow you to retrieve stats for dynamic links created through the API. You can see the docs here: analytics api docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic Links created using the API are not displayed in the Firebase console. You can instead use the Firebase Dynamic Links Analytics API. As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics) says

> You can use this REST API to get analytics data for each of your short
>   Dynamic Links, whether created in the console or programmatically.

Ref: [Dynamic Links Analytics API Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics)